# MySQL JOIN to get available photos

Tags: mysql, join

So here's my problem. I have two tables, `photos` and `users_homepage_photos`. In my site users need to be able to pick from their uploaded photos and tick them so they appear on their site homepage.

The `photos` table stores all the photo data (image URL, name, caption, etc.), and the `users_homepage_photos` table is a cross-reference table comprised of `id`, `user_id`, and `photo_id`.

**I want to write a query that will get all the photos *available* for use on the homepage**, therefore selecting all photos that are NOT already in the `users_homepage_photos` table.

My query so far is this (with `photos.user_id` being 4 as my test user ID):

```
SELECT photos.id, photos.user_id, photos.s3_thumb, photos.`name`, photos.`date`, photos.`caption`,
    users_homepage_photos.*
FROM photos
JOIN users_homepage_photos ON users_homepage_photos.`photo_id` != photos.id AND users_homepage_photos.`user_id` = 4
WHERE photos.user_id = 4
```

**Here's the problem:** - when the user has 1 photo already in the `users_homepage_photos` table, the query works perfectly and selects all photos except for that photo already in there.

**However** if the user has NO photos on their homepage, the query selects 0 rows. **How can I get it to select all the rows in this case?**

Thanks!

Jack

**EDIT**: Screenshots with data examples.

`SELECT * FROM users_homepage_photos`:

[image: example query]

`SELECT * FROM photos WHERE user_id = 4`

[image: query]

Finally, when I run the query that @gbn posted (the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` variant of my query):

[image: query]

Hope that sheds some light on the situation.

Comment: -1 for 1. refusing to give desired sample output 2. posting misleading query with superfluous columns.

Comment: Eh? Don't mean to be a party-pooper here but 1. I have been busy/elsewhere without time to update the question and respond to comments, and 2. I get a downvote because my query is not as efficient as it could be? Isn't the point of constructive discussion to help amateurs like myself improve their skills through feedback? Nowhere did I see you make any other mentions of 'superfluous columns' or the like.

Comment: Also it's a shame you deleted your answer as I did actually find it useful and helpful in several regards, such as improving my knowledge of how OUTER JOINs work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT photos.id, photos.user_id, photos.s3_thumb, photos.`name`, photos.`date`, photos.`caption`
FROM photos
WHERE(photos.user_id = 4)AND(NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users_homepage_photos WHERE users_homepage_photos.`photo_id` = photos.id))
```

Comment: And how do you then get users_homepage_photos.* into the output?

Comment: Brilliant, this seems to work perfect each time! Thanks for your help. Am I right in thinking this is actually two queries in one?

Comment: Left it there by mistake (edited now), as I understand it is actually not needed in the output? Quote from question "selecting all photos that are NOT already in the users_homepage_photos table".

Comment: Having said that, getting `users_homepage_photos.*` is not necessary for the output. It's never required when outputting the HTML etc. I just need to query against it and this query seems to get all the right rows.

Comment: @Jack It is called "subquery"